# Need help solving a javascript Caesar Cipher problem

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck doing the Caesar cipher problem. For those of you familiar with the problem, I'm not able to wrap around the alphabet, for example if I want to shift the string 'z' by 1, instead of getting 'a', i'll get '['. I know the reason this happens but I'm not able to come up with the proper code. Any help will be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
const caesar = function(word, num) {
  let solved = ""
  num = num % 26;
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length ; i++) {
    let ascii = word[i].charCodeAt();
    if ((ascii >= 65 && ascii <= 90) || (ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122)) {
      solved += String.fromCharCode(ascii + num) ;
    } else {
        solved += word[i]
      }
 }
 return solved;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the modulus under 26 after subtracting the char code of the first letter of the alphabet and add it back afterward to allow the cipher to wrap around. You will need to handle capital and lowercase letters separately.

```js
const caesar = function(word, num) {
  let solved = ""
  num = (num%26 + 26) % 26;
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length ; i++) {
    let ascii = word[i].charCodeAt();
    if ((ascii >= 65 && ascii <= 90)) {
      solved += String.fromCharCode((ascii - 'A'.charCodeAt(0) + num)%26 
        + 'A'.charCodeAt(0)) ;
    } else if(ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122){
        solved += String.fromCharCode((ascii-'a'.charCodeAt(0) + num) % 26 
       + 'a'.charCodeAt(0));
    } else {
        solved += word[i]
    }
 }
 return solved;
}
console.log(caesar("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHI", 7));
```

Comment: Hey thank you kind stranger. I'm new to this so I don't really understand your code fully but I will study it carefully. So it has mostly worked but when I enter the following:  console.log(caesar('B', -5)); I get '=' instead of 'w'

Comment: @SamuelOkoth When you enter what?

Comment: thanks so much, it works now...mind breaking it down for me? also do you mind taking on an apprentice? You solved this so quickly after I had posted it and I'm looking to improve my code...let me know what you think :)

Comment: @SamuelOkoth As for explanation, you need to take modulus under 26 so that values larger than 26 can wrap back around. Subtracting the first letter of the alphabet is to ensure that you only get values in the range 0-25, after modulus.

Comment: lol my bad i'm new on the site. Had no idea I could accept answers

Comment: @SamuelOkoth Also, I'm rather busy, so I'm afraid I would not have time for an apprentice.

Comment: ah, shame! thanks for everything though and goodluck :)

Comment: @SamuelOkoth No problem. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Do the modulus when you add num to your ascii value.  This way you don't scroll past the end of the range (and loop around if you are through the modulus (remainder)).

solved += String.fromCharCode((ascii + num)%26) ;

Comment: Also, don't forget to add the base number (starting point, A or a).  The lower-case and upper-case range of the table are different number ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, the ASCII codes for 'A` and 'a' are 0x41 and 0x61 respectively: upper and lower case letters differ by whether bit 0x20 is set (lower case) or not set (upper case).

Hence a bit-bashing algorithm to circular shift ASCII letters and maintain case would be strip the lower case bit, perform the shift, and re-insert the case bit:

```js
"use strict";
function caesarShiftLetter( letter, num) {
    let code = letter.charCodeAt(0);
    let lowerCaseBit = code & 0x20; // 0 or 0x20
    let upperCaseCode = code - lowerCaseBit;
    if( upperCaseCode < 0x41 || upperCaseCode >= 0x41 + 26) {
        return letter;
    }
    num = 26 + num%26; // handle large negative shift values
    upperCaseCode = ((upperCaseCode - 0x41) + num) % 26 + 0x41;
    return String.fromCharCode( upperCaseCode | lowerCaseBit);
}

// to test:

function caesarShiftString( str, num) {
    return Array.from(str).map(char => caesarShiftLetter( char, num)).join('');
}

console.log( caesarShiftString(
    "abc ... xyz, ABC ... XYZ, I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX, X - 1,3,4,5,6,7,9, 10",-22
    )
);
```